# How to find .mp4 files in a specific directory and create txt file with additional text wrapped around the filenames

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I'm new to the Mac Terminal. I am attempting to provide ffmpeg a .txt file containing a list of .mp4 files from a directory to concat into a new file.
**For this post, I only want to focus on creating the list in the way that ffmpeg requires.**

My directory has four files: 
file1.mp4 
file2.mp4 
file3.mp4 
otherclip.mov

I need to have the command line look at this directory, ignore the .mov file and create a txt file in the following way.

file 'file1.mp4' 
file 'file2.mp4' 
file 'file3.mp4'

Assuming I'm already in the correct directory how do I loop through the files and place the .mp4 files in a txt file with the text ***file 'filename.mp4'*** wrapped around it?

I saw someone on Windows successfully do this by running
`for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('dir *.mp4 /b') do echo file '%~ni%~xi' >> list.txt` 
I'm not sure what the bash equivalent would be but when I ran that in my terminal it returned `` -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"tokens=*"' ``

Comment: Please list the actual directory showing actual names. From the comments below it's obvious that your files are *not* called `file1.mp4` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are in the the directory these files exist-

file1.mp4
file2.mp4
file3.mp4
otherclip.mov

and the output that you want into a text file is named list.txt, you could redirect the output of the following into the named file-

```
printf "file '%s'\n" *.mp4 > list.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
cd directory/with/videofiles
for f in *.mp4; do
    echo "file '$f'" >> ./file-for-ffmpeg
done
```

should do.

Or

```
cd directory/with/videofiles
ls *.mp4 | sed -E "s|(.*)|file '\1'|" > ./file-for-ffmeg
```

if you look for a simple one-liner.

Comment: I am in the proper directory when running these commands. When running the first block line by line the last line starting with mv throws  the operation not permitted command. That said, I do get a file-for-ffmpeg at the Finder window. When I manually add .txt to the end of it I can open and see the document contains the text **file 'file*mp4'**

Comment: Using cp instead of mv prevents the error from being thrown but the txt file still just reads **file 'file*mp4'**

Comment: When I run `cd /directory/with/videofiles
rm -f /tmp/t
for f in file *.MP4; do
    echo "file '$f'" >> /tmp/t
done
cp /tmp/t ./file-for-ffmpeg.txt` I do get a .txt file with my list of files but the first line of the txt file reads **file 'file'** How would I get rid of that?

Comment: When I run `cd /directory/with/videofiles rm -f /tmp/t for f in file*.MP4; do echo "file '$f'" >> /tmp/t done cp /tmp/t ./file-for-ffmpeg.txt` I get a .txt file whose only content reads **file 'file*.MP4'**

Comment: If the files have lowercase extensions (i.e. `.mp4`, not `.MP4`), then you need to use lowercase in the pattern: `for f in file*.mp4`. If there's a mix of upper- and lower-case extensions, then use `for f in file*.[mM][pP]4` to match both.

Answer (score -1):

The following worked for me:
`for f in *.MP4; do echo "file '$f'" >> list.txt; done`